# gpg asks for password when supplying it in a file?

Tags: shell-script, shell, encryption, gpg

Trying to run this:

```
gpg -c --passphrase-file secret somefiletoencrypt
```

But it still asks for a password.

How do we make gpg use the password in the `secret` to do symmetric encryption?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the `gpg` manual (`man gpg2` on my system), in the section talking about the `--passphrase-file` option:

> Note that since Version 2.0 this passphrase is only used if the
>   option `--batch` has also been given. Since Version 2.1 the
>   `--pinentry-mode` also needs to be set to `loopback`.

Testing for myself with GnuPG 2.2.12, adding `--batch` to your command makes it work as expected.